# How to convert '.bak' file into '.sql' file in order to import the database in MySQL phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I'm a **PHP developer** by profession. I'm using **Ubuntu Linux** on my machine.

I don't have any idea about **.Net framework** and **MS SQL Server Express** database.

I've received a file titled **project_db.bak** and I have to convert it into **project_db.sql** in order to import the same database into MySQL.

I searched over the Internet for the solution. I found couple of answers but they are asking to use MS SQL server tools which I can not. I have to achieve this conversion in some other way.

Can someone please help me in this regard?

Comment: From command prompt `mv project_db.bak project_db.sql`

Comment: Why can't you use ms sql tools? SQL Server Express is free, so is SQL Server Management Studio. Converting an existing ms sql database to mysql will be smoother, but still probably you will need texternal tools to do the conversion.

Comment: Or just browse to the `mv project_db.bak` I dont think phpMyAdmin cares what the file is called that it imports from

Comment: But if the file came from SQL Server I doubt it will just import as the 2 databases are quite different in many ways

Comment: @Shadow: I can't use ms tools because I'm using Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 0):

MS Sql Server typically generates binary backups, so what you have I guess is a backup.  To restore it to a "querable" state **you will need** MS tools or `RESTORE` statment someway executed against the Motor (that you will need). Once it was "restored" (that is the reverse to a MS backup) you can dump (in MySql terms) with a tool or with a script

Comment: I can't use ms tools because I'm using Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: @PHPLover well, get a windows box as well.

Comment: Well, sorry but... 1- there is curently no way to run MS Sql Server on Ubuntu,  2- there is curently no way to restore a binary MS Sql Server backup to other RDBMS than MS Sql Server

Comment: OK fine, Does that require dot net framework/Visual Studio installed on the windows machine? Better can you please add the steps to the answer about how to achieve this using windows machine? From scratch, please!!!

Comment: @PHPLover the steps are simple because they are generic: 1) Restore the bak file to an ms sql server instance 2) Using an ms sql to mysql conversion tool convert the database to mysql (recommending a tool is off-topic on SO).

Comment: Will it work simply from Windows machine or Visual Studio/.Net framework/SQL Express Server, etc. do also be needed to be installed on it?

Comment: No, It just requiere any version of SQL server, not visual studio, not dot net framework.  You should ask to the one that gave the backup to you, in what Sql Server it was taken, in order to have the same version or later.  Again, binary backups do not restore on old versions of Sql Server.  If you use the latest Sql Server Express I think it allows up to 10Gb databases. In other case you will need a paid version, or a site that will let restore online to their servers

Comment: To clarify, you can even not to ask for the version at all. Get latest version of MS Sql Server Express, install and try to restore. (But) some old versions of binary backups are not supported. The sure path is to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Virtual Machine Windows 7 or better.

In the VM make sure you have a second network card that's set to a private network with your Host so you can connect to your Host MySQL you will need a User in your MySQL Server setup that allows connections from your remote network

in this VM install `SQL Server`, and `SQL Server Management Studio` & `Navicat` from that you can then restore the .bak file, once you have it restored. you will need another external tool that allows you to export as another format for this i use `Navicat` export is as another format. you can then connect to your MySQL Server and import that exported file.